# Wordpress: wp_update_attachment_metadata returns false

Tags: php, wordpress

I am adding image via this function but somehow `wp_update_attachment_metadata` is returning me false. please help me

```
if (isset($imageValues['name'][$k]) && !empty($imageValues['name'][$k])) {
    $blogImage = wp_upload_bits($imageValues['name'][$k], null, file_get_contents($imageValues['tmp_name'][$k]));
}

if (is_array($blogImage) && $blogImage['error'] === false) {
    $file_path = $blogImage['file'];
    $file_name = basename($file_path);
    $file_type = wp_check_filetype($file_name, null);
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $attachment = array(
        'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'].'/'.basename($file_path),
        'post_mime_type' => $file_type['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($file_path)),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
    );

    $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, basename($file_path));
    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $file_path);
    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation it will return false, if you pass in an invalid post to begin with. Are you sure you actually have a post ID in `$attachment_id`?

Comment: yes there is attachment id. I got a lead whenever i add $attachment_data['live-blog'] = true; just before wp_update_attachment_metadata it returns true

Comment: "`wp_update_attachment_metadata` is returning me false" - I hate to sound pedantic, but I'm not seeing any of these checks. `wp_insert_attachment` returns `int|WP_Error`, `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` returns an array which could be empty, and the mentioned function can return false, too, but there's no `if` or similar checks anywhere